# Q2017: How do I set a scheduled transaction group to "auto" enter?

Tags: quicken

I have a Quicken file that was started in 2007 and I recently updated to Quicken 2017.

I have four "transaction groups", three of which show a status of "Auto" and automatically enter into their respective registers.  The remaining group says either "Upcoming" or "Overdue" and will not automatically enter.

I have run validations on the data file and even used "file operations" to create a copy and then opened that copy; the results are the same.

*How do I change a transaction group to the "auto" setting?*

Alternatively, how do I create a *new* group with this setting as the new groups I've tried creating are also **not** "auto".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about technology.

Comment: The tag description says, "For questions related to the Quicken personal finance software. As this is a personal finance site, questions about usage of the software are preferred over technology-related questions."  I guess I misunderstood the meaning of "usage of the software"...  in which case, yes, it would be off-topic.  Is there a better StackExchange site on which to post it?

Comment: It's on-topic, Brian.